# Problem with style file (.qml) loading in QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, style, qml

I am trying to load a .qml style file to CORINE land cover maps, but the application generates an automatic color ramp.

**Dataset**:http://geoforall.hu/sites/default/files/geodata/clc-series_hun.zip

**Update:** The problem still exists in QGIS 3.4.

In QGIS 3.2 after loading qml, if I click "Apply" then colors change:
[image: After applying the colors change.]

In QGIS 2x, loading the style from the qml works as expected:

[image]

The problematic CLC .qml style file:

```
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis version="1.7.0-Trunk" minimumScale="0" maximumScale="1e+08" hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag="0">
  <transparencyLevelInt>255</transparencyLevelInt>
  <rasterproperties>
    <mDrawingStyle>SingleBandPseudoColor</mDrawingStyle>
    <mColorShadingAlgorithm>ColorRampShader</mColorShadingAlgorithm>
    <mInvertColor boolean="false"/>
    <mRedBandName>Not Set</mRedBandName>
    <mGreenBandName>Not Set</mGreenBandName>
    <mBlueBandName>Not Set</mBlueBandName>
    <mGrayBandName>Band 1</mGrayBandName>
    <mStandardDeviations>0</mStandardDeviations>
    <mUserDefinedRGBMinimumMaximum boolean="false"/>
    <mRGBMinimumMaximumEstimated boolean="true"/>
    <mUserDefinedGrayMinimumMaximum boolean="false"/>
    <mGrayMinimumMaximumEstimated boolean="true"/>
    <mContrastEnhancementAlgorithm>NoEnhancement</mContrastEnhancementAlgorithm>
    <contrastEnhancementMinMaxValues>
      <minMaxEntry>
        <min>0</min>
        <max>255</max>
      </minMaxEntry>
    </contrastEnhancementMinMaxValues>
    <mNoDataValue mValidNoDataValue="true">0</mNoDataValue>
    <singleValuePixelList>
      <pixelListEntry pixelValue="0" percentTransparent="100"/>
    </singleValuePixelList>
    <threeValuePixelList>
      <pixelListEntry red="0" blue="0" green="0" percentTransparent="100"/>
    </threeValuePixelList>
    <customColorRamp>
      <colorRampType>DISCRETE</colorRampType>
        <colorRampEntry red="255" blue="255" green="255" value="0" label=""/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="77" green="0" value="111"       label="111 - Összefüggő település szerkezet"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="255" blue="0" green="0" value="112"        label="112 - Nem-összefüggő település szerkezet"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="204" blue="242" green="77" value="121"     label="121 - Ipari vagy kereskedelmi területek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="204" blue="0" green="0" value="122"        label="122 - Út- és vasúthálózat és csatlakozó területek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="204" green="204" value="123"    label="123 - Kikötők"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="230" green="204" value="124"    label="124 - Repülőterek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="166" blue="204" green="0" value="131"      label="131 - Nyersanyag kitermelés"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="166" blue="0" green="77" value="132"       label="132 - Lerakóhelyek, meddőhányók"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="255" blue="255" green="77" value="133"     label="133 - Építési munkahelyek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="255" blue="255" green="166" value="141"    label="141 - Városi zöldterületek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="255" blue="255" green="230" value="142"    label="142 - Sport-, szabadidő-és üdülő területek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="255" blue="168" green="255" value="211"    label="211 - Nem-öntözött szántóföldek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="255" blue="0" green="255" value="212"      label="212 - Állandóan öntözött területek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="0" green="230" value="213"      label="213 - Rizs földek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="0" green="128" value="221"      label="221 - Szőlők"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="242" blue="77" green="166" value="222"     label="222 - Gyümölcsösök, bogyósok"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="0" green="166" value="223"      label="223 - Olajfa-ültetvények"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="77" green="230" value="231"     label="231 - Rét / legelő"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="255" blue="166" green="230" value="241"    label="241 - Egynyári kultúrák állandó kultúrákkal vegyesen"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="255" blue="77" green="230" value="242"     label="242 - Komplex művelési szerkezet"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="77" green="204" value="243"     label="243 - Elsődlegesen mezőgazdasági területek jelentős természetes növényzettel"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="242" blue="166" green="204" value="244"    label="244 - Mezőgazdasági-erdészeti területek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="128" blue="0" green="255" value="311"      label="311 - Lomblevelű erdők"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="0" blue="0" green="166" value="312"        label="312 - Tűlevelű erdők"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="77" blue="0" green="255" value="313"       label="313 - Vegyes erdők"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="204" blue="77" green="242" value="321"     label="321 - Természetes gyepek, természetközeli rétek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="166" blue="128" green="255" value="322"    label="322 - Hangafüves, harasztos területek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="166" blue="77" green="230" value="323"     label="323 - Keménylombú mediterrán növényzet"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="166" blue="0" green="242" value="324"      label="324 - Átmeneti erdős-cserjés területek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="230" green="230" value="331"    label="331 - Homokos tengerpartok, dűnék, homok"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="204" blue="204" green="204" value="332"    label="332 - Csupasz sziklák"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="204" blue="204" green="255" value="333"    label="333 - Ritkás növényzet"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="0" blue="0" green="0" value="334"          label="334 - Leégett területek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="166" blue="204" green="230" value="335"    label="335 - Gleccserek, örök hó"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="166" blue="255" green="166" value="411"    label="411 - Szárazföldi mocsarak"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="77" blue="255" green="77" value="412"      label="412 - Tőzeglápok"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="204" blue="255" green="204" value="421"    label="421 - Tengermelléki mocsarak"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="255" green="230" value="422"    label="422 - Sólepárlók"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="166" blue="230" green="166" value="423"    label="423 - Ár-apály által érintett területek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="0" blue="242" green="204" value="511"      label="511 - Folyóvizek, vízi utak"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="128" blue="230" green="242" value="512"    label="512 - Állóvizek"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="0" blue="166" green="255" value="521"      label="521 - Tengerparti lagúnák"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="166" blue="230" green="255" value="522"    label="522 - Folyótorkolatok"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="255" green="242" value="523"    label="523 - Tenger és óceán "/>
        <colorRampEntry red="0" blue="0" green="0" value="999"          label="999 - NODATA"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="255" blue="255" green="255" value="990"    label="990 - UNCLASSIFIED LAND SURFACE"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="230" blue="255" green="242" value="995"    label="995 - UNCLASSIFIED WATER BODIES"/>
        <colorRampEntry red="255" blue="255" green="255" value="990"    label="990 - UNCLASSIFIED"/>
    </customColorRamp>
  </rasterproperties>
</qgis>
```

Comment: Similar issue https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/284872/2856

Comment: I downloaded your data and i didn't have problems, what is your problem?
could you show us an image?

Comment: An imperfect solution if you use the same name for the .qml and .tiff file.

Comment: @Carlos López Quintanilla : What version do you use?

Comment: I use QGIS 3.2 "Bonn"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to modify this template:

```
**Here is an example of a working .qml:**
`<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis version="2.18.18" minimumScale="inf" maximumScale="1e+08" hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag="0">
  <pipe>
    <rasterrenderer opacity="1" alphaBand="-1" classificationMax="11.485" classificationMinMaxOrigin="unknown" band="1" classificationMin="0.5" type="singlebandpseudocolor">
      <rasterTransparency/>
      <rastershader>
        <colorrampshader colorRampType="DISCRETE" clip="0">
          <item alpha="179" value="1" label="&lt;= 1" color="#0571b0"/>
          <item alpha="179" value="4" label="1 - 4" color="#92c5de"/>
          <item alpha="179" value="6" label="4 - 6" color="#f7f7f7"/>
          <item alpha="179" value="8" label="6 - 8" color="#f4a582"/>
          <item alpha="166" value="inf" label="> 8" color="#ca0020"/>
        </colorrampshader>
      </rastershader>
    </rasterrenderer>
    <brightnesscontrast brightness="0" contrast="0"/>
    <huesaturation colorizeGreen="128" colorizeOn="0" colorizeRed="255" colorizeBlue="128" grayscaleMode="0" saturation="0" colorizeStrength="100"/>
    <rasterresampler maxOversampling="2"/>
  </pipe>
  <blendMode>0</blendMode>
</qgis>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I gonna check it, and accept if working.

Comment: I removed some parts of your answer, which mislead me a bit. The provided good template solved the issue, after the review I will accept your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped you. I feel like the current answer will not be very helpful to many people especially those new to QGIS. Did this method work for you? In QGIS 3:
Go to layer properties > style. Now load the qml but before closing the dialog open "Min/max value setting" and select "User defined".

Comment: @pnz Could you explain how this answer helped with the problem?

Comment: I don't remember well, but I suppose I've recreated the layer style with this template.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my original answer with more details in case that helps. 
In QGIS 3:
Go to layer properties > style. Now load the qml but before closing the dialog open "Min/max value setting" and select "User defined". 
As described by Ernst Kuilder in his answer [Proper assignment of QML legend to raster failed in QGIS 3.0.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284872/proper-assignment-of-qml-legend-to-raster-failed-in-qgis-3-0-1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

A different work around is to edit raster .qml styles created in QGIS 2.x that don't work when appled in QGIS 3.x.
Because .qml are a very simple file I found that if I opened up the .qml in a text editor and replaced **classificationMinMaxOrigin=** with a value of either **"CumulativeCutFullExtentEstimated"** or **"MinMaxFullExtentEstimated"** with **"unknown"** it would then work.

**Here is an example of a broken .qml:** 
`<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis version="2.18.18" minimumScale="inf" maximumScale="1e+08" hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag="0">
  <pipe>
    <rasterrenderer opacity="1" alphaBand="-1" classificationMax="11.485" classificationMinMaxOrigin="CumulativeCutFullExtentEstimated" band="1" classificationMin="0.5" type="singlebandpseudocolor">
      <rasterTransparency/>
      <rastershader>
        <colorrampshader colorRampType="DISCRETE" clip="0">
          <item alpha="179" value="1" label="&lt;= 1" color="#0571b0"/>
          <item alpha="179" value="4" label="1 - 4" color="#92c5de"/>
          <item alpha="179" value="6" label="4 - 6" color="#f7f7f7"/>
          <item alpha="179" value="8" label="6 - 8" color="#f4a582"/>
          <item alpha="166" value="inf" label="> 8" color="#ca0020"/>
        </colorrampshader>
      </rastershader>
    </rasterrenderer>
    <brightnesscontrast brightness="0" contrast="0"/>
    <huesaturation colorizeGreen="128" colorizeOn="0" colorizeRed="255" colorizeBlue="128" grayscaleMode="0" saturation="0" colorizeStrength="100"/>
    <rasterresampler maxOversampling="2"/>
  </pipe>
  <blendMode>0</blendMode>
</qgis>`

**Here is an example of a working .qml:**
`<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis version="2.18.18" minimumScale="inf" maximumScale="1e+08" hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag="0">
  <pipe>
    <rasterrenderer opacity="1" alphaBand="-1" classificationMax="11.485" classificationMinMaxOrigin="unknown" band="1" classificationMin="0.5" type="singlebandpseudocolor">
      <rasterTransparency/>
      <rastershader>
        <colorrampshader colorRampType="DISCRETE" clip="0">
          <item alpha="179" value="1" label="&lt;= 1" color="#0571b0"/>
          <item alpha="179" value="4" label="1 - 4" color="#92c5de"/>
          <item alpha="179" value="6" label="4 - 6" color="#f7f7f7"/>
          <item alpha="179" value="8" label="6 - 8" color="#f4a582"/>
          <item alpha="166" value="inf" label="> 8" color="#ca0020"/>
        </colorrampshader>
      </rastershader>
    </rasterrenderer>
    <brightnesscontrast brightness="0" contrast="0"/>
    <huesaturation colorizeGreen="128" colorizeOn="0" colorizeRed="255" colorizeBlue="128" grayscaleMode="0" saturation="0" colorizeStrength="100"/>
    <rasterresampler maxOversampling="2"/>
  </pipe>
  <blendMode>0</blendMode>
</qgis>`